# Configure a router with multiple web proxy options

Tags: linux, networking, router, proxy

Over the years I have become quite disappointed with the routers that are available in shops to buy and I've decided that it's about time I built my own. But one of the things I really want to do (at the router level, so I don't have to configure each device attached on the network) is to have the option of using different web proxies.

Example I have to proxies: Proxy A and Proxy B.
On the router what I would like to do is to have some logic that goes as follows

```
IF url == "example.com"
    use Proxy A
ELSE
    use Proxy B
```

Anything like this possible? 
Thanks